# Java reflection method invoking error

Tags: java, api, reflection, overriding

I'm making a kind of test program to be able to override methods in classes for an api I'm making in java but I'm getting a weird error when trying to invoke a method from another class...

Here is the main "component class":

```
 package st.cmp;

 import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
 import java.lang.reflect.Method;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.List;

 public class Component {

public class Overrider{
    Class<?> source;
    Class<?>[] overs;
    String name;
    public Overrider(Class<?> s,String n,Class<?>[] o){
        source=s;
        overs=o;
        name=n;
    }
    public Object call(Object[] param){
        try {
            return source.getMethod(name, overs).invoke(this, param);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
};


public HashMap<String,Component> cmps;
public HashMap<String,Overrider> over;

public Component(){
    cmps=new HashMap<String,Component>();
    over=new HashMap<String, Overrider>();
}

public void registerComponent(String nm,Component cm){
    cmps.put(nm,cm);
}
public Component getComponent(String nm){
    return cmps.get(nm);
}

public void override(Class<?> cl,String name,Class<?>[] param){

        over.put(name,new Overrider(cl,name,param));

}

public Object call(String mnm,Object[] a){
    Overrider ov=over.get(mnm);
    if(ov!=null){
        ov.call(a);
    }

    Class<?>[] abc=new Class<?>[a.length];

    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        abc[i]=a[i].getClass();
    }

        try {
            return this.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(mnm, abc).invoke(this,a);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
                | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException
                | SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            try {
                this.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(mnm, abc).invoke(this,a);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
                    | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException
                    | SecurityException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    return null;
}

public void test(String a){
    System.out.print(a);
}

public int add(Integer a,Integer b){
    return a+b;
}
 }
```

And this is the main class:

```
package st;

 import st.cmp.Component;

 public class Start {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Start().start();
}
public void start(){
    Component a=new Component();
    a.call("test",new Object[]{a.call("add",new Object[]{1,5}).toString()});

    a.override(this.getClass(), "add", new Class<?>[]{Integer.class,Integer.class});

    a.call("test",new Object[]{a.call("add",new Object[]{1,5}).toString()});
}
public int add(Integer a,Integer b){
    return a*b;
}

 }
```

I'm getting this error when I start the program:

```
6java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at st.cmp.Component$Overrider.call(Component.java:22)
    at st.cmp.Component.call(Component.java:64)
    at st.Start.start(Start.java:16)
    at st.Start.main(Start.java:8)
6
```

Can anyone help me?

it says "object is not an instance of declaring class"... But what "object" is it refering to?

Comment: Whatever object you're trying to invoke a method on. Step through your code with a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Start` class, you are calling the `Component.override()` method:

```
//         v--- This is the Class Object
a.override(this.getClass(), "add", new Class<?>[]{Integer.class,Integer.class});
```

Where `a` is of type `Component`. You are passing it `this.getClass()`, which is a Class object for `Start`. Then in `override()`:

```
//                          v--- Class object gets passed along here
over.put(name,new Overrider(cl,name,param));
```

You are creating a new `Overrider`, and giving the Class object for `Start` to the constructor, which sets the `Class<?> source;` field to the `Start` Class object. Then when you call the `Overrider.call()` method, it does this:

```
//     v--- and finally invoked here
return source.getMethod(name, overs).invoke(this, param);
```

And passes `invoke()` a `this` which is an instance of `Component`, while `source` is a Class object for `Start`. In this line, "source" and "this" need to be the same class, but `Start` and `Component` aren't.

Comment: if your saying that I should pass 'source' as a parameter to the invoke method then it causes the same error as always...

Comment: @Fred I'm saying because they are different, you are getting that error. Obviously, your `source`, which is a Class object for `Start`, doesn't have an `add()` method, so you can't invoke `Start.add()`, however, since the class `Component` has an `add()` method, the source should be a `Component.Class`.

Comment: Start does have an add method (at the bottom) which should override the add method in Component...

Comment: @Fred then are you sure when you call `source.getMethod(name, overs).invoke(this, param);` that you are replacing *`this` with an instance of `Start`*? `source` is an Object of type `Class`, and `this` needs to be an instance of that type.

Comment: I have no idea how I missed that! Thanks for the help... I've been messing with this for over 3 hours today!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite convoluted, but this my help. If you have a line like this:

```
klass.getMethod(name).invoke(obj)
```

then the error says that `obj` is not an instance of `klass`.